Setting up Resend and React Email in a Remix project. Error - Dynamic require of ‘stream’ is not supported
I'm having trouble finding much info on setting up React Email and Resend in Remix. I want to set up a forgot password page that sends the user a token to their email.
Code from my forgot password page.
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  // if there is a user logged in, then they should know their password..
  const userId = await getUserId(request);
  if (userId) return redirect("/");

  // Get token from password rest link
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const token = url.searchParams.get("token");

  // if (!token) {
  //   return json({ message: "Invalid token. Please try again. " });
  // }

  // Go grab the user that matches the token
  let user;
  if (token) {
    user = await getUserByToken(token);
  }

  return json({ user });
};

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const { _action: rawAction, ...values } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  const { email, password, confirmPassword } = values;

  //Form Action: Send password reset email after validating user
  if (rawAction === "send_password_reset_email") {
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      return json({ errors: { email: "Email is invalid" } }, { status: 400 });
    }

    // get user with the valid email supplied
    const user = await getUserByEmail(email);

    if (!user) {
      return json(
        { errors: { email: "Can't find your account." } },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    // Go update the user with a password reset token
    const updatedUser = await updateUserToken(email);

    // Send email with password reset link
    try {
      if (updatedUser.password) {
        const resetEmail = await sendPasswordResetEmail(
          updatedUser.password.passwordResetToken,
          email
        );
        console.log("reset page", email, updatedUser.password.passwordResetToken)
        return json({ message: "Email sent" });
      } else {
        // Handle the case where updatedUser.password is null
        // You might want to return an error message to the client
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return json({ error });
    }

    //Form Action:  Reset the user password in db
    const _action = rawAction as "send_password_reset_email" | "password_reset";

    if (_action === "password_reset") {
      if (typeof password !== "string") {
        return json(
          { errors: { password: "Password is required" } },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      }

      if (password.length < 8) {
        return json(
          { errors: { password: "Password is too short" } },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      }

      if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        return json(
          { errors: { confirmPassword: "Password doesnt match" } },
          { status: 400 }
        );
      }

      // Update the user with the updated password
      const resetPassword = await updateUserPassword(email, password);

      return json({ message: "Password reset" });
    }
  }
};

export default function ResetPage() {
  const data = useLoaderData() as Data;
  const actionData = useActionData() as ActionData;
  const emailRef = React.useRef(null);
  const user: User | undefined = data.user;

  console.log(data, actionData);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (actionData?.errors?.email && emailRef.current !== null) {
      (emailRef.current as HTMLInputElement).focus();
    }
  }, [actionData]);

Then I have what I call a helper function to pass the info to the email to send.
import { Resend } from "resend";
import { ForgotPassword } from "../emails/ForgotPassword";
import { render } from "@react-email/render"
import { getUserByEmail } from '../.server/models/user.model';

const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);

export async function sendPasswordResetEmail(resetToken, to) {

  if (!to) {
    throw new Error("Email address is required");
  }

  const user = await getUserByEmail(to);
  
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }

  const reset_link = process.env.FRONTEND_URL + "reset?token=" + resetToken;

  try {

    await resend.emails.send({
      from: "Your email", // Change to your verified sender
      to: user.email, // Change to your recipient
      subject: "Your subject",
      html: render(ForgotPassword({ to, user, reset_link })),
    });

    console.log("Email sent");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

Then here is my text email made with React-Email. I think this might be where the problem lies if not it could be that these programs are not made to work with remix or I'm not using them right. IDK?
import {
  Body,
  Button,
  Container,
  Column,
  Head,
  Heading,
  Html,
  Img,
  Preview,
  Row,
  Section,
  Text,
} from "@react-email/components";
import * as React from "react";
import type { User } from "~/.server/models/user.model";

interface ResetTokenProps {
  to?: string;
  user: User | null;
  reset_link?: string;
}

export const ForgotPassword = ({
  to,
  user,
  reset_link,
}: ResetTokenProps) => {
  if (!to) {
    throw new Error("Email address is required");
  }
  if (!user) {
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }

  return (
    <Html>
      <Head />
      <Preview>Title or some thing to help the user know they want to open this email</Preview>
      <Body style={main}>
        <Container>
          <Section style={logo}>
            <Img src={``} />
          </Section>

          <Section style={content}>
            <Row>
              <Img style={image} width={620} src={``} />
            </Row>

            <Row style={{ ...boxInfos, paddingBottom: "0" }}>
              <Column>
                <Heading
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 32,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    textAlign: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  Yo {user.username},
                </Heading>
                <Heading
                  as="h2"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 26,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    textAlign: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  Can't remember your password? Happens all the time.
                </Heading>

                <Text style={paragraph}>
                  Just click the button below and we'll get you through these
                  choppy waters and back to the high seas of the internet.
                </Text>
              </Column>
            </Row>
            <Row style={{ ...boxInfos, paddingTop: "0" }}>
              <Column style={containerButton} colSpan={2}>
                <Button href={reset_link} style={button}>
                  Reset Password
                </Button>
              </Column>
            </Row>
          </Section>

          <Section style={containerImageFooter}>
            <Img style={image} width={620} src={``} />
          </Section>

          <Text
            style={{
              textAlign: "center",
              fontSize: 12,
              color: "rgb(0,0,0, 0.7)",
            }}
          >
            © 2024 | Info-tagline-whatever you want here |
            www.yourwebaddresshere.com
          </Text>
        </Container>
      </Body>
    </Html>
  );
};

// Mock user for preview
const mockUser = {
  id: "1",
  email: "sally@example.com",
  username: "Sally",
  firstName: "Sally",
  lastName: "Mc Sal Sal",
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
  role: "guest", // replace with actual role type
};
  
ForgotPassword.PreviewProps = {
  to: "sally@example.com",
  user: mockUser,
} as ResetTokenProps;
  
export default ForgotPassword;

const main = {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  fontFamily:
    '-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif',
};

const paragraph = {
  fontSize: 16,
};

const logo = {
  padding: "30px 20px",
};

const containerButton = {
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  width: "100%",
};

const button = {
  backgroundColor: "#e00707",
  borderRadius: 3,
  color: "#FFF",
  fontWeight: "bold",
  border: "1px solid rgb(0,0,0, 0.1)",
  cursor: "pointer",
  padding: "12px 30px",
};

const content = {
  border: "1px solid rgb(0,0,0, 0.1)",
  borderRadius: "3px",
  overflow: "hidden",
};

const image = {
  maxWidth: "100%",
};

const boxInfos = {
  padding: "20px",
};

const containerImageFooter = {
  padding: "45px 0 0 0",
};


Found the solution. Replace "react: emailContent" with "html: render(ResetPasswordEmail({ to, user, reset_link })),"

What version of react-email are you using? I think this issue is the problem: https://github.com/resend/react-email/issues/1486

See my comment as well: https://github.com/resend/react-email/issues/1486#issuecomment-2181007726

HI @LukeDunscombe I'm using 2.1.4
